# ODE with modulus sign

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I solve this ODE ?
$$\left|y'(x)\right| +\left|y(x)\right| =0.$$
I can easily solve it without the modulus signs. At present, $y(x)=0$ is the ony solution I can think of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $y\neq 0$. Then
$$
\frac{|y'|}{|y|}+1=0\iff \left\lvert\frac{y'}{y}\right\rvert=-1
$$
which is not possible.

Comment: Didn't think like this. Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

Hint. $\left|a\right| +\left|b\right|=0$ if and only if $a=b=0$.

Comment: Makes sense. Is there any mathematical proof of your statement ?

Comment: Yes. $0=|a|+|b|\geq |a|\geq 0$ implies that $|a|=0$, that is $a=0$. The same for $b$.